# Unique predual of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Assume that there exists a norm-closed subspace $Y$ of $X^{*}$ such that

1. $Y$ is a predual of $X$ (when each element in $X$ is viewed as an evaluation map), and
2. For any predual $Z$ of $X$, the natural inclusion $i_{Z}:Z\rightarrow X^{*}$ sends $Z$ inside $Y$.

I've concluded that in this case $Y$ must be the unique predual of $X$. But I can't trust my proof, as it seems that the topic of preduals is not so benign to me and is full of non-intuitive examples.

Is my conclusion true?

If it is, where can I find a reference?

If it isn't, what's wrong with my proof, as roughly goes as follows?

1. On the closed unit ball of $X$, $\sigma(X,Y)$ and $\sigma(X,Z)$ are the same, because both makes the ball compact Hausdorff but one is certainly finer than the other.
2. Any $y\in Y$ is $\sigma(X,Z)$-continuous, because a linear functional on a dual space is weak-$*$ continuous if and only if its restriction on the closed unit ball is weak-$*$ continuous by Banach-Dieudonne theorem.
3. $Z$ is precisely the set of $\sigma(X,Z)$-continuous linear functionals, which shows that $Y=Z$.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want pre-duals to be complete?

Comment: Of course, I assumed a predual means a Banach space.